# What is the best way to move a single site from one MS installation to another?

Tags: customization, multisite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production)

I have a dev, staging and production installation of WP MS.  And I am trying to figure out what is the best way to move a site created in the dev environment to the staging environment.

Since MS uses one large database, I would be moving a group of tables vs an entire database.  It worries me that I will corrupt the database.

Comment: I'm sorry. Not to be thick, but what does "MS" stand for in this context? And are you concerned about moving content (posts, Pages, tags, etc) or themes, plugins, etc.?

Comment: MS, in general, refers to MultiSite (formerly WordPress MU - Multi User).  It's a new feature of WordPress 3.0 that allows for multiple sites to be run on top of one installation of the WordPress codebase.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation would be to use WordPress' built-in import/export mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the export / import mechanism would be the best way to go.  I *think* the multisite database layout is incompatible with a single site configuration.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this was already answered somewhere else:

[How to: Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production)