# Moving to directory creates path problems.. how to solve?

Tags: installation, directory

I've moved my installation from `example.com/beta` to `example.com` and I've noticed that there are a few broken images. Looking at the source, it appears that they are still looking in looking in the `/beta` directory for the images.. How can I fix this?

The pics which are broken seem to be the ones uploaded from within the page/post editor.

(Note:I exported the database to a file and there were many instances of example.com/beta in it .. I wonder if I can find-replace to get rid of the beta and then import the db..?)

EDIT

In the end, I went into each post, and edited each broken image (Edit Image > Advanced Settings) to take out the `beta/` before wp-content. I was too scared to edit the exported sql and re-import it. If it happens in the future I would just re-create the `/beta/wp-contents/uploads` with the contents of `/wp-contents/uploads` until I found the patience to go thru and change each image paths.

Comment: Images in post content? More details please on how were they added (media attachment, FTP upload, etc).

Comment: yes, images added within pages/posts. not images used in css etc.

Comment: Using image attachment? Sorry for bugging for details, but there are maaaany ways to abuse images in WP. :)

Comment: Using the Upload/Insert > Add an image > 'Select files' button, when you are editing a post/page.. The images were inserted into the page when the site was in /beta

Comment: You might want to place your solution in a separate answer and mark it as accepted. That way, the system knows this question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

When images are added to WordPress posts and pages, they are stored with the *absolute url* to the image file on the server.  If you change your WordPress installation (move to a different domain, change your folder structure, etc) then you'll break these images.  There are two ways to fix this:

#### Manually re-write URLs

The most time-consuming path is to sit down and do a find/replace on all image URLs in your site.  If you have a large site, this can take forever to do by hand and you'd be well-served writing a script to do it for you.  Do a search on the [WP support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/) and you'll find a host of pre-written scripts to do just that, but most require a higher level of technical skill or access to your site than most people have.

#### Use a rewriting plug-in

I've moved my blog a few times.  It started out as http://eamann.com/wordpress/.  Then it moved to http://eamann.com/mindshare/.  Then it was http://mindshare.eamann.com.  Then it moved to its current home at http://mindsharestrategy.com.  Each time, I had the same problem you're facing now - my images broke.

Rather than manually re-writing my image URLs each time, I installed a redirection plug-in to do it for me.  After the first move, if you requested http://eamann.com/wordpress/image1.jpg the server would instead give you http://eamann.com/mindshare/image1.jpg.

You could use a similar redirection script to point all requests to `example.com/beta/###` to `example.com/###`.  There are several redirection plug-ins available, but **[this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/)** has a very refined UI and is very easy to use.

Comment: The rewriting seems very hack-ish, and the plug-in linked to seems to be broken for WP 3. I exported the database to a file and there were many instances of example.com/beta in it .. I wonder if I can find-replace to get rid of the beta and then upload?

Comment: Find-replace works just fine (remember, that was the first suggestion) and it's what I had to do when I moved my site to a new domain on a different server.  Rewriting only works if you're still on the same system ... and as you can see from the 10/33 split on the compatibility widget, it works on some instances of WP3 ... but obviously not all.  It works on my site (WP 3.0.1) or I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually update your database to fix images path on posts / pages.
I believe there's plugin that do this. I'll update this answer later when I found one.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, this [post on SQL queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/correct-search-replace-queries-for-changing-urls-in-a-wordpress-database) could be helpful to some folks.
There is also a [commercial product from iThemes](http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) that might be useful, especially if you're going to do this kind of move regularly.

Answer (score 1):

If it is down to it - [plugin for search and replace in WP with serialized support](http://spectacu.la/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Just be sure to backup and everything. I'd first test on local copy of database if possible.