# Update Pages ONLY from Stage to Live (not products)

Tags: pages, post-meta, staging

I have a WordPress site that has a bunch of posts, a bunch of pages and a bunch of products (Woocommerce ones). I Staged the site and made loads of changes to the pages on stage, meanwhile the live site posts and products grew and grew. Now I am ready to deploy the changes that I made to the pages on stage on to the live site, however, when I publish the "...posts" and the "...postmeta" tables they overwrite the products.

So, how do I publish the changes I made on the stage site pages without impacting any other content?

FYI - my pages are built using Elementor, but i do not think that factors in this.

Kind regards,

John

Comment: This is a common problem alas, e.g. [this old question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/database-synchronization-between-dev-staging-and-production?rq=1). I'm surprised there aren't any good solutions around, or at least I can't find any on a quick search.

Comment: Thanks - the post you linked doesn't really help. The XML import option imports new pages, i want to update the pages already there with the new content fro the staging server. The MySQL option may work but i don't know enough about MySQL, can swot up on it (and should) but it is not a quick solution. Unless i use MySQL it does look like there is not solution here :-(

Comment: Can't actually find MySQL to do this either...this seemed such a simple update to make, get updates on pages on stage and push those changes and only those changes to live, but extensive searching i have found no solution. Seems like i will have to do each page update manually which will take at least a week. Major issue imo.

Comment: Yes, the reason I linked you to an old question was because this is a longstanding issue (more than I expected there to be a good solution there). I'd have hoped the XML export would include a post GUID though and the import would see the GUID already existed and update. (And it could be enhanced to do that?)

Comment: The most promising thing I found searching was this [wpdatamerge.com](https://wpdatamerge.com/) except it doesn't exist yet :-/ It sounds like it's precisely the solution though.

Comment: That woud be awesome as i think, as you said, it would do just the trick. I also hoped that would be the case but no such joy. I have tried a few different ways and searched for hors for solution but again no joy. I am still looking at SQL option, if not will have to do it manually for now and keep an eye on wpdatamerge