# how do i find out why links point to my old domain

Tags: migration, domain-mapping

i migrated a wordpress site from one domain to another.  I still have images and links that seem to be pointing to my old domain name.

where can i get a list of all places in wordpress that hardcode or has the domain name in it.

the only place i saw was in the database in the **wp_posts** table in the **guid** column.  where else should i be looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about changing the guid, you'll be fine if you never update that field. The main places you'll need to update are in the **post_content** column of **wp_posts** (for links and images), and in the **wp_options** table (for widget data).

Before you do any database replacing, though, read through this thread:

[How to: Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production)

There are some helpful tips there, and there are plugins that will do most of the work for you.

Comment: very helpful.  my one open issue is that the top picture on my heading is still pointing to the old domain. do you know where i change that ?

Comment: also, i can't log into my dashboard.  when i go to:  wp-admin/admin.php, i get the login screen but after logging in, it takes me to a blank screen.  any thoughts?

Comment: @ooo - both are those are most likely issues in the **wp_options** table. There are entries in there for 'home' and 'siteurl': make sure both of those are pointing to your current domain. Your header image location could be set any number of places. Most themes store that info in wp_options, but you're better off getting into your dashboard and changing it there.

Comment: updating every value in wp_options brought my header picture back which is great.  my final problem is i still can't get to the dashboard. I get the login screen but after login, it takes me to a blank screen . .

Comment: i figured it out.  i was going to: http://blog.kantro.net/wp-admin/admin.php and i tried going to just: http://blog.kantro.net/wp-admin and it worked fine . .thanks for your help