# How to replace the domain name in a WordPress database?

Tags: mysql, migration

I have a WordPress database which was installed in a development environment... thus, all references to the site itself have a fixed IP address (say 192.168.16.2). Now, I have to migrate that database to a new WordPress installation on a hosting. The problem is that the SQL dump contains a lot of references to the IP address, and I have to replace it with: my_domain.com.

I could use `sed` or some other command to change the that from the command line, the concern is that there are a lot of configuration data which uses JSON. So what? Well, as you know, JSON arrays uses things like: `s:4:` to know how many chars an element has, and thus, if I just replace the IP with the domain name, the configuration files will get corrupted.

I used an app for Windows some years ago that allows to change values in a database and takes care of the JSON arrays. Unfortunately, I forgot the name of the app... so the question is: do you know any app that allows me to do what I want?

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, but might help you out in searching for one: the data you're looking at is not JSON formatted. JSON doesn't (normally) store value types and lengths like that. What you're looking at is SERIALIZED data. A google search for "mysql replace serialized" yields this page, which might help: http://davidcoveney.com/mysql-database-search-replace-with-serialized-php/

Comment: Hey, your comment is the only answer that was useful for me... move it to an answer to mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data you're looking at is not JSON formatted. JSON doesn't (normally) store value types and lengths like that. What you're looking at is SERIALIZED data. A google search for "mysql replace serialized" yields this page, which might help: http://davidcoveney.com/mysql-database-search-replace-with-serialized-php/

Comment: Thank you... I worked as PHP developer for 2 years. I can't believe I forgot the difference between something serialized and a JSON string.

Comment: this has a github repo now: https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Answer (score 11):

Codex has decent guide - [Changing Site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/).

Basically there are several places there URL matter or not so much (I may be missing some):

- `home` and `siteurl` options that control where WP thinks site is;
- post GUIDs, these look like links but really they aren't - only identifiers. I am not absolutely sure they are irrelevant, but I had URLs change on test stack a lot and never bothered to update these.
- links in post bodies;
- possibly links in plugin settings.

Comment: There's quite a few steps. After you `mv olddir.com newdir.com` you'll need to reconfigure your webserver, restart the webserver. Follow the codex instructions here and then you should be able to login as admin. That should get you started :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can set these values with the constants in the `wp-config.php`. After this you can, when you want, change the entries in the database tool like 'PhpMyAdmin' or 'Adminer'.

Write this in the `wp-config.php` and the values in the DB are not relevant:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/to-wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/to-blog');
```

Answer (score 7):

As Rarst said above there's only two settings in the database that NEEDS changing. After importing the database I log into PHPMyAdmin and edit the database direct.

I use a development server on my PC all the time to import datafeeds and they have the URL attached to the Posts along the lines of http://localhost/testsite/post-name/ and it's never caused a problem.

I used to use an SQL search and replace until I realised it didn't matter. I've migrated a few sites from one domain to another and where I've had absolute URLs in the content I'll use the SQL search and replace option.

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content,'http://www.olddomain/','http://www.newdomain/');
```

David

Comment: There are some plugins, like ContactForm7, which also saves the domain name inside a serialized string, among with other configuration variables. When you modify a serialized string it can get corrupted if its length changes, so in fact, sometimes, there are more things to change than just two settings.

Answer (score 6):

This is an amazing resource i have bookmarked that I go back to time and time again
http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/01/30/13-useful-wordpress-sql-queries-you-wish-you-knew-earlier/

They state

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://www.newsiteurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple SQL queries - no complicated REPLACE stuff required:

```
update wp_options set option_value = 'http://mynewdomain.com' where option_name = 'siteurl';

update wp_options set option_value = 'http://mynewdomain.com' where option_name = 'home';
```

Use those with PHPMyAdmin or any other way you prefer to access the database.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the new database selected, then run some sql updates and replacement commands on the tables notably, wp_options, wp_posts, wp_postmeta.

Use the code as below and swap in your old and new URLs, no trailing slashes. Also if necessary change the table prefix values where applicable (ie wp_ )

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http_www.oldurl', 'http_www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';    
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http_www.oldurl','http_www.newurl');    
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http_www.oldurl', 'http_www.newurl');    
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http_www.oldurl','http_www.newurl');
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look my answer to this question:

- [**Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production/182#182)

It addresses your issues with cleaning up data and can be customized for specific data migration needs by using using hooks, too.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but since I came across it while looking for something else, I thought I would add this for future reference.

I think the simplest, most complete way to do this is using searchreplacedb2.php.  It can be found here: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ along with an explanation of it's use.

It has definitely saved me a lot of time with migrating from dev to live environments on my wordpress sites.

Just make sure you delete it from a public server after you are done!

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to move your WordPress site from the development environment to a new server or production server.

Recently, I have moved my site to the production server and I face the same situation. I need to update the site URL because WordPress stored the site URL in Database.

I found good MySQL query using that I can easily change URL directly from the Database like.

```
SET @search := "http://olddomain.com";
SET @replace := "http://newdomain.com";

UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "siteurl";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "home";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "product_list_url";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "shopping_cart_url";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "checkout_url";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "widget_text";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "headerImageLogo";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "cunjo_plugin_url";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "wpsr_socialbt_data";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "issuem";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "_transient_dgxdonate_t70pbg1htu_1396322372";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "dgx_donate_log";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "headerBackgroundImage";
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = REPLACE(option_value, @search, @replace) WHERE option_name = "transact_url";
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`=REPLACE(meta_value, @search, @replace);
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value`=REPLACE(meta_value, @search, @replace);
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `guid`=REPLACE(guid, @search, @replace);
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content`=REPLACE(post_content, @search, @replace);
```

You just need to replace your site URL from old domain name to new domain then execute the query on the MySQL using PHPMYADMIN.

For more reference, You can read [this](https://tryvary.com/wordpress-change-url-in-database-using-mysql-query/) Tutorial.

https://tryvary.com/wordpress-change-url-in-database-using-mysql-query/