# Wordpress database synch between dev and prod

Tags: staging, sync, production

Question has been asked before about how to synchronize files as well as the database between two Wordpress installations.

For the database level, the answer is usually to basically dump one database and insert it onto another server. The problem with this is that you end up losing any changes that have potentially been made on the prod server. For instance, usage metrics, comments, etc...

With this in mind, I was starting to wonder whether the it would be possible to extend the Wordpress ORM so that you can generate deltas and then inject those into the prod site.

Has anyone tried this, looking into it, or have any ideas or comments ?

Comment: I have looked into it, yes, but haven't accomplished much. If you could point to a proof-of-concept with another CMS platform, I'm sure we could rejigger it for WordPress.

Comment: How about replication?

Comment: Well replication with mysql would require some form of master-master replication which is a PITA. If you factor in the fact that this is between dev and prod, then replication would have to be delayed which would most likely break all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reality is that what we want is this: http://www.liquibase.org/

> Liquibase is an open source (Apache 2.0 Licensed),
>   database-independent library for tracking, managing and applying
>   database changes. It is built on a simple premise: All database
>   changes are stored in a human readable yet trackable form and checked
>   into source control.

However our development process doesn't support it.  We typically don't modify the database through discrete scripts we write ourselves, we use plugins that we activate.  We don't write DML scripts to modify look-up data that we then check into source code control, we use a UI on the admin page and therefore have no source code for later use in replicating that change during migration.

However, we can emulate some of it -- using some of the tools listed on this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/225772/149060

For instance, liquidbase has a diff feature that also, optionally includes changes to data.  We could, potentially, output the schema and data diff to a script, excluding (as possible) certain tables likely to include test data ( i.e. post, etc. ) and then apply the script to the production database.

MySQLDiff (discussed on the StackOverflow question) does schema diffs, and it's author recommends [mysql_coldiff](http://rossbeyer.net/software/mysql_coldiff/) for table-wise data diffs - both are implemented in perl, if java tools (liquidbase) are too resource heavy for your servers -- although bring both databases local and running the tool on your PC solves that problem ...

If we really want to do it right, we should log any sql that relates to settings, options, or other configuration changes, and any schema changes -- and convert the logged code into a migration script to play against our production server.  Play the migration script against the server, copy the wordpress site files (excluding uploads, if applicable) and we're gold.

So, it seems to me, that the best way out, is a developer's migration-builder-plugin that traps the sql we need, stores it and then generates a migration script from the logged code, rather than to build a way to merge databases between staging and production.  Seems a simpler problem to solve too.

If we look at the code of @bueltge 's instrumenting hook calls plugin for inspiration: https://gist.github.com/1000143 (thanks to Ron Rennick via G+ for pointing me in the  direction of SAVEQUERIES and the shutdown hook, that lead me to find it)

```
-- alter it to get the SAVEQUERIES output instead 
-- only run while in admin 
-- filter out all selects 
-- save results out to table in the shutdown hook 
-- we could selectively toggle output trapping based on what we were doing at the moment.
```

For example:

Capture Name: Activate & Configure Plugin XYZ

Capture State Toggle - on

... install and configure plugin XYZ

Capture State Toggle - off

Export Migration Script for: Activate & Configure Plugin XYZ

Press Export Button -- to produce a popup text field with the filtered trapped SQL - ideally pre-formatted as a shell script with command-line call to mysql.  Copy & paste it out to your migration code folder and add to your source code repository.

Careful attention to toggling the capture on and off as you're working and you'll be able to generate the perfect migration script to take your production database to an equivalent configuration to your staging database.

What's better, you'll have a script (or series of same) that you can TEST.  Imaging having replicable, testable, migration scripts!!

I'm in love already.

Anyone else?

Comment: Nice writeup. I've been spending lots of time on this problem because I've got clients looking for our help it. It's a really hard problem, but we've decided that going down to the level of SQL is probably a too much of a *"boil the ocean"* solution meaning chances of getting it to work 100% are unlikely. I think the solution is use a *"divide-and-conquer"* approach with explicit code that understand's WordPress' structure, and that provides hooks for anything else. I hope we can present a viable solution publicly at some point in the future.

Comment: So.... who wants to make this?

Comment: for anyone looking, seems this same idea is available as a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-recorder/

Answer (score 3):

The **[Database Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/database-sync/) WordPress plugin** does a great job of syncing data between two servers.

By default it overwrites ALL destination data, however I've just implemented some enhancements to the plugin which allow you to only sync specific database tables.  This can help you retain comments, users and other such data that you don't want overwritten.  Does that give you the granularity that you need?

I haven't released my changes to the public yet, but if you're interested in a copy, send me an email at simon-at-yump.com.au.  If anyone finds this useful or has additional feature requests, let me know and I'll see what I can do.

---

**UPDATE:** I've also just found the [**WP-Sync-DB**](https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db) plugin, which is a fork of the commercial *WP-Migrate-DB-Pro* plugin.  It does a very similar thing, although probably has more polish than *Database Sync*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively new commercial service specifically for this task. It's called RAMP:

http://alexking.org/blog/2011/07/20/ramp-content-deploy-wordpress

Comment: There are limitations to that service that make it not fit my use case:

Comment: My use case - adding functionality while production adds content. Quote: "The following items are currently unsupported: Settings (core and plugin settings, unless they opt-in to RAMP)"  99.99% of theme and plugin options and settings won't migrate.  Without code changes on production, custom post-types won't migrate.  Forget about adding custom tables and their data.

Comment: That product does have a valid use-case -- staging content and then pushing it live.  Unfortunately that's not the problem I'm concerned with.  Checking back to the OP, it's unclear which use case he's dealing with - so it might be the perfect solution for their shop.