# Is there an easy way of exporting posts with their category already asigned and pictures from localhost?

Tags: database, export

Every time I export a database using the Export Tool in wp-admin. There are two things left out: The category 'checked' (I have to do that all over again every time I export the posts). Also I can't download the pictures because I usually work in my localhost.

How to export absolutely everything (100%) from the database of a Wordpress site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export everything in the database, go to your hosting provider's control panel such as [CPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/) and find out how to do *"an SQL dump"*. An SQL dump is a text file containing the SQL script to rebuild your database on your local computer. You can often do that in software your host may provide named [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/).

Alternately you could use a [desktop SQL tool](http://www.google.com/search?q=desktop+MySQL+tools); if you are on Windows one of my favorites is the free [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/); on Mac I used the commercial software [Navicat for MySQL](http://www.navicat.com/) which I also used on Windows because of advanced features that HeidiSQL did not have. If you use a desktop tool you will probably have to [enable remote access to MySQL from your IP address](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database).

After you've imported your SQL dump, you can consider using [this plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production/182#182) to *"fix up"* all your URL references.

Hope this helps.

-Mike

P.S. You'll need to use FTP to download all of your photos and other files you may have uploaded.