# What is the best practice to get a site from local to online?

Tags: multisite, migration, backup

I develop my sites on a local xamp setup.
When I´m done I need to get the site to my customer´s domain.

Can I use vault press or backupbuddy for this, or is there a better process ?

Answer (score 1):

Related question: [How to: Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production)

Comment: I read that article, but unfortunately there´s nothing easy to that for me. Seems just as much work as I´m having to do now duplicating stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use either one of those tools to move one of the sub site to its own single site.

you'll be moving it just like you move stuff off WordPress.com. Except you also have database access.

Comment: I was afraid of that. The do however tell me that a lot of their users use backupbuddy for migration ???

Comment: It seems like backupbuddy has this feature. They advertise it on their homepage.

Comment: from their page "in WordPress 3.0′s multisite, it backs up the entire set of sites on the single WP installation."

Comment: so I could use that and remove the sites I don´t want?

Comment: you could, but it's be about the same amount of work and you'd still have a network. albeit with one site, but still a network. not a single site. Ad if the one you wanted to keep was not the main site in the network, you;d have to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will give this a try. It sounds easy enough ;o)
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/exporting-and-importing-wordpress

Comment: another one that doesn´t work with multisite ...

Answer (score 0):

You might tale a look at myEASYbackup plugin.  I used it recently to clone a site on a different domain, and it handled full URL references in the database pretty well.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn´t handle MU as yet

Answer (score 0):

I´m trying to get my head around this [article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production), and I think I got it ;o)

step1: upload all theme and plugin files via FTP

step2: On the live domain create a new database and import your local dbase (or does
       upload the development MySQL database something else?)

step3: edit your wp-config as described.
       Can I leave out the test, stage, dev registrations if I don´t have them?
       I migrate from local to live domain.

step4: then run the plugin form the new live site.

[@mikeschinkel](http://@mikeschinkel) Is this the correct process?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move a MU blog to its single site, you'll need to copy all the blog's tables PLUS wp_users and wp_usermeta tables which are common to all the network sites.
don't forget to change the uploads directory path.