# How to Mirror WordPress database from Remote server to Local server

Tags: database, mysql, export, sync

Before I embark on this tutorial from the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/MacOS_X_Local_Mirror) on mirroring a WordPress database from a remote server to a local one. I'd like to get some feedback from SE users who have successfully achieved this, or who have followed the same tutorial.

Here are my questions:

1. What methods have you guys used to mirror/sync your databases?
2. What kind of MySQL software do you use (or think is the most reliable), in terms of importing/exporting MySQL dumps
3. Is there a risk of data loss during the transfer?

Comment: this question has been asked a few times - have you searched here for previous answers?

Answer (score 1):

[Database synchronization between dev/staging and production](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/database-synchronization-between-dev-staging-and-production)

[How to: Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production)

[Maintaining synced staging/production WP sites](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/maintaining-synced-staging-production-wp-sites)

Comment: thanks, the second link is extremely helpful. Though my 2nd and 3rd questions still stand, those links barely scratched surface. I'm currently using [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/), which I'm really happy with, but configuring it to the right settings can be confusing, at least to my level knowledge. I was just wondering if there's any risk (even if its miniscule) of data loss when exporting MySQL dumps from a remote server.