# How might I setup a development server (local) and a test/production server (remote)

Tags: server, customization

I am thinking, how might I setup a development server locally then when done, upload and sync files + data to test/production server? I think options like `siteurl` and `home` in `wp_options` database table will need to be changed, also, in `wp-config.php` some settings like database connection and debug mode will be different too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite difficult to keep data from a dev version in sync with data on the production site. But for an initial deployment, you are correct that it requires changes to wp-config.php and the database.

- Install Wordpress on your dev machine, e.g. dev.example.com/blog/
- Install Wordpress on your production machine, preferably with the *same folder structure* as the dev box, e.g. www.example.com/wordpress/
- note: your wp-config.php settings will be different on production. That's fine, just maintain a safe copy of the file and do not overwrite.
- Sync the /wp-content/ directory from dev to production (themes, plugins, etc)
- Using PHPMyAdmin or similar, export the contents of your dev database to a text file
- In the text file, replace any instances of the dev url with the production url (dev.example.com/wordpress/ => www.example.com/wordpress/). This will change the siteurl as well as any links to images in the posts
- Using PHPMyAdmin or similar, import the contents of your dev database to the production database
- Try accessing the Wordpress admin module in the production server - you should be good to go.

This technique works for me, but I'd love to hear of any cleaner migration techniques.

UPDATE: There are a number of techniques discussed in the following post, including a plugin that handles the db grunt work:
[How to: Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production)