# Clone plugins (and settings) to new installation?

Tags: options, staging, deployment

Is it possible to clone the plugins and settings from a WordPress site to a new fresh install?

I don't want any of the content from the original site I just want all the plugins used and their settings.

Just ftp'ing the plugins into the new install doesn't work.

It's really important that all the settings are saved from the one site to the other as this will save a huge amount of time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually blog settings, sidebars and plugins option are located in wp_options table. If you copy whole table except option_name IN ( 'siteurl', 'home' ), You get whole "old" configuration.

Comment: Is there an easier way than this?

Comment: I copied the database down, uploaded all the files from the old site to the new hosting (I changed the database details in the wp-config). I then uploaded the database to the new database. I then went to the login screen for the new site, put in my details but it redirected me to the old site's cms!

Comment: in wp_options table, search for values with the old URL and change them for the new. If the problem still exist, check for url in the .htaccess file too.

Comment: I've shown hidden files in my ftp client but it doesn't show a htaccess file anywhere. Is it possible to remove all the old site's content but keep the plugin data/settings?

Comment: Ok, I went into the database for the new site and in the wp_options table I changed the siteURL from the old site to the new site and it's now going to the correct admin. The next problem is that all the pages have the url's of the old site, is this a case of changing the general settings on the new admin?

Answer (score 0):

I use blogzapper to clone WordPress installations and it works surprisingly well.  It costs around $30.  I use it t0 try out new code on clone sites before migrating to a live site.

It will clone your whole install, and then you would have to manually delete your content, but it should still save you loads of time.

http://www.datasystemsplus.net/blog-zapper

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a database export to a .sql text file.
2. Do a find/replace in the text file for http://www.olddomain.com and replace with http://www.newdomain.com.  This will correct all the old settings across all your posts and options table.
3. Import file in the new database / website you created.