# Plugins to clone wordpress site and move to another url

Tags: migration, installation, clone-site

Are there any possible plugins that could clone an entire Wordpress site and install it in another location?

I build sites on one url, then to show the client and move it to another url to show it.

At the moment copying the files and database and re-uploading everything and changing urls is a bit of a nightmare!

UPDATE:
I want them to run off two different databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicator/

I tried duplicator and it worked out great. A 25min process condensed down into 5mins, really simple to use and has now worked several times for several sites, great plugin!!

Answer (score 2):

There is extensive question/answers for moving from development to produciton in general [Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production)

However for your specific question best plugin that I know is commercial [BackupBuddy](http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/). It packs whole site (including WP itself) and can restore it to different URL.

Answer (score 2):

In this years Google Summer Of Code at WordPress, there is a project called [WordPress Move](http://gsoc2011.wordpress.com/wordpress-move/). The WordPress team is working with the student on developing this new function (now as a plugin, maybe someday in core code). It appears to work already, but it is still in development.

Check out the [posts tagged with 'wordpress move'](http://gsoc2011.wordpress.com/tag/wordpress-move/) on the WordPress GSoC 2011 blog, for more info on this project.

Answer (score 0):

I agree on using the Duplicator plugin. I tried it recently and it worked without a hitch. the instructions were a little lacking but I was able to figure it out.