# Contents of HTML editor mangled after multiple UPDATES

Tags: html-editor

In a perfect world, WordPress would take what I enter into the HTML editor and write it verbatim into the post/page document received by the browser. Disabling `wpautop` has already helped me slightly to this end. Alas..

**Setup:** I write some HTML into the editor and click UPDATE. My post/page is formatted correctly, but the contents of my editor have changed: `p` and `br` tags are gone, replaced respectively with actual empty lines and line breaks. When I view source, the contents of the editor `textarea` are what I originally typed, but its as if `p` and `br` tags are actually being rendered in the `textarea`.

**The problem is that when I click UPDATE again (without changing anything), the post/page is formatted incorrectly, because said tags are lost.**

How can I get my HTML editor contents not to be automatically mangled? I do not ever switch over to the visual editor. Just scanning through `wp-includes/formatting.php`, the function `format_to_edit` seems promising, but unsure how to proceed.

**Example**

1. Enter `<p>Hello</p>` in HTML editor for new post
2. Click PUBLISH, published post is formatted correctly
3. Contents of editor changed after the PUBLISH refresh to `Hello` (p tags gone)
4. Click UPDATE, post is formatted incorrectly due to lack of p tags

---

**UDPATE**

*After looking at some of the comments/answers and doing some testing, this does look like a hackery side-effect. I can't repro in a fresh install of Roots. Here are the details of my install:*

1. Customized [Roots](http://rootstheme.com) theme, no hackery.
2. Plugins: Akismet, Advanced Custom Fields, Custom Post Type UI, Google Analytics for WP

Comment: Looks like a side-effect of some hackery stuff.

Comment: Why do you need the markup to begin with?

Comment: @TomJNowell so that the post is formatted/spaced correctly.. and so that my site outputs clean semantic markup.

Comment: Then you've got it completely wrong. Adding p tags for spacing purposes is not semantic at all, the same with br tags ( which I advise against ). Spacing is a stylesheet thing not a html thing.

Comment: What you're trying to do is bad practice, it's wrong, use css instead. ( and avoid <br> tags where possible )

Comment: @TomJNowell CSS needs tags to hook onto, and the problem is only magnified if I'm adding rich styling to `p` tags that are disappearing.

Comment: WordPress automatically adds CSS tags already, if you need to emphasis something in content, implement a shortcode with div tags. If you need to emphasise something use <em> ( the emphasise tag ). If all of the above is not enough ( e.g. you need to emphasise something inside a bold red underlined paragraph ) then you are doing it wrong, and you seriously need ot look at learning how to write because you're just screaming at the reader at this point.

Comment: I'm also painfully aware that nowhere have you posted an example detailing exactly what you put in, what you expected, and what you got instead.

Comment: @TomJNowell touche, I added an example. I appreciate your concern for my markup habits, but it's not what this question is about. My goal is to know WordPress well so that I can deliver for my clients. Not interested in resigning to it's quirks.

Comment: That's expected behaviour, you're not meant to put p tags in the content editor, the hacky part is why your post requires them, since it should be wrapping it in a p tag automatically at runtime

Answer (score 1):

It may help you to render content in your theme directly without `the_content` filter, although you would loose thigns like oembeds etc e.g.:

```
echo $post->post_content;
```

However this sounds like a symptom of a hack. If you have something complex like an embed then you should be using either oembed ( e.g. youtube, don't be pasting the raw embed stuff ) or using a shortcode. Else there's very, very few reasons to keep the html markup for things like p and br tags for ordinary content, and if you're using div containers and other layout elements then you're doing it wrong

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of my _editor contents_ being changed. I'm happy with what WP is outputting in my theme.. it's just that the original markup I write in the editor is lost after I UPDATE again, so I have to paste in entirely fresh markup every time I make a change.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once and it was caused, as Ashfame comments and Tom J Novell mentions, by a double hackery stuff.

My *functions.php* was removing some `the_content` filters and a plugin (don't remember which) was doing the same.

There are some basic troubleshooting steps that you may take. They are outlined in [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-33-master-list) by the always cognoscenti [Ipstenu](http://profiles.wordpress.org/ipstenu). I'll reproduce the steps bellow, but the article is worthwhile reading in full.

> - flushing any caching plugins you might be running, as well as server and/or browser caches.
> - deactivating all plugins (yes, all) to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you
>     find the problematic plugin(s). If you can't get into your admin
>     dashboard, try resetting the plugins folder by FTP or PhpMyAdmin.
>     Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems.
>     Also remember to deactivate any plugins in the mu-plugins folder. The
>     easiest way is to rename that folder to mu-plugins-old
> - switching to the Twenty Eleven theme to rule out any theme-specific problems. If you can't log in to change themes, you can remove the
>     theme folders via FTP so the only one is twentyeleven. That will force
>     your site to use it.
> - manually upgrading. When all else fails, download a fresh copy of the latest.zip file of 3.3 (top right on this page) to your computer,
>     and use that to copy up. You may need to delete the wp-admin and
>     wp-includes folders on your server. Read the Manual Update directions
>     first!

If it is complicated for you to practically shut down a live site for doing this, two options:

- do it at 5AM in the timezone of most of your visitors
- clone the site and troubleshoot locally
- - [references](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups) for [manual](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/25390/12615) [cloning](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/119/12615)
- - free option: [XCloner](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/)
- - premium option: [BackupBuddy](http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/)