# Copying Wordpress site, HOW about the DB connection?

Tags: admin

I am USING the wordpress Import/Export and have done exporting the XML file from my wordpress site. And now i am moving my site from a local server to a host, after copying the files i noticed that on the new HOST there is no DATABASE connection, since i am not using a fresh install, I am just copying my files from the local server to the new HOST. How can i resolve this by not using any database client from the new host like PHPmyAdmin, is their a wordpress plugin that can solve this? THere is a BIG Error establishing a database connection on my page
thank you

Comment: Do you have a database setup on your host? Do you know the DB name and the DB username/password?

Comment: YEs, but i am documenting a transfer for a end user may not get what phpMyAdmin is or whats a config. Or the reality that i really need to teach him a fresh install. . or a plugin maybe for DB connect

Comment: If you're not going to setup the database for the end user, then yes: the end user will need to be comfortable enough with the tools required in order to setup/install WordPress, including cPanel/phpMyAdmin or whatever.

Comment: That seems to be a good answer, thank you and a major remake of the documentation . . thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're copying your content by means of a WordPress import/export, you'll need to install WordPress on your new host as a fresh install, and put your new DB details in your wp-config.php.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to modify wp-config.php. You can set the DB connections there.

Look for a section similar to this:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', '');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer here: [Developing, Testing and Releasing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36547/developing-testing-and-releasing/36550#36550)

You should really setup a conditional wp-config to minus out your headaches during deployments.

Hope this helps!