# Local and live synchronized dev and production environment

Tags: customization

First sorry for my bad english  :)

I'm a beginner of wp and I wonder how to manage/synch the follow dev environment :
- Local and live dev (local server xampp and staging subdomain dev.mywebsite.ext) - After how to update to production environment  on www.mywebsite.ext considering eventual new content added from visitors/users.

So in other words how can i manage the syncronization beetween the 3 envirnment (2 dev and 1 produztion) withouth lost anything (contents, files, database):

xampp <--> dev.mywebsite.ext <--> www.mywebsite.com

thanks

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but apart from `wp-config.php` tweaks or using a plugin catered to handling this situation, all of the solutions are really the same for any type of website, WordPress or not. Seasoned developers tend to leverage their version control software (like Git) or a virtual-machine manager to deploy their plugins and themes to different servers. Usually you keep your databases separate in each environment, maybe occasionally downloading your live DB to your dev environment to work with new content (it's pretty rare that people do the reverse).

Comment: See [36547](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36547), [238250](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238250), and [119](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119) for some more perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start to look at versioning now you will not regret it later! It's one of the biggest improvements you can make to your development workflow.

You work locally. Commit files as they change, and they are then deployed (even automatically, if you are happy with that) to your live server.

I recommend you look at something like http://www.beanstalk.com which makes version control less scary.

Once you have this working, you can enhance it with Chrome plugins like "Server Switcher" and simply snap between local and live servers on the fly.

Comment: Of course versioning it's important, but I would like to understand wich tools/plugins/software and wich configurations use to get like in this image :
http://prntscr.com/exfkpy

Comment: You could achieve that very easily with git/subversion running on Beanstalk as I suggested. All you would need is XAMPP, something like Tortoise SVN as a local client, and Beanstalk. That's it (Plus a staging and live server of course). You'd use Beanstalk to deploy "on commit" (automatically) to the staging server, and deploy manually to live after review. Which Beanstalk would also help achieve with multiple developers.

Comment: Maybe you mean that ?  : http://beanstalkapp.com   ?
Anyway there is not a free alternative ?

Comment: Yes I meant that, and it is free for small teams and limited projects. Is there anything else I can do for you before you accept my answer? :)