# Installation question

Tags: database, installation

I am a brand new developer to wordpress and about to begin work on a client's website that is already up and running.  The site is very simple, it is more-or-less just a brochure with very little use of the database (only for customer reviews which at the moment only has about 5 reviews)

My question is what kind of credentials I need besides the admin login info to begin work on their site? The client is an elderly couple with no computer skills at all.

Will I need to install the LAMP stack to work on their site? Do I need to install wordpress to work on their site?

How do I have access to the database? I know these all sound very trivial but many of the tutorials / installation I see on the web is for starting a brand new project.  Keep in mind, someone worked on this before for them.  I'm too new to wordpress to know if source files are required or is it all within the admin page? Thanks

Comment: It will be good to have FTP access, and if possible access to Cpanel. If you are planning to make changes to the live site, that's all you will need. But unless these are content changes you shouldn't make changes to the live site. You will need LAMP to run the website local. If you are on a mac using MAMP is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that your do the get the following from theme.

1. There host. It is good to know a persons host before starting work on there website.
2. You should make sure that you have full admin access, or if they have multisite then Super Admin. This way you can have all the freedom to make the changes.
3. FTP/cpanel access. They don't need to give you access to there host login, but you should make sure that you always have access to there FTP before starting any work on there website.
4. Lastly I would make sure that you make a full backup of there entire website (MySQL database, public_html, etc.) before starting any work at all on there website.

If you have access to the FTP, and admin then you should be good.

As for localhost I would recommend using MAMP. It is more lightweight then other ones like XAMPP and it is super easy to install and set up. If you are going to make a lot of changes then you should defiantly use a localhost website and transfer the website over. To do this I would checking out this [article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/how-to-easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production). If you do all your changes on your localhost then it ensures that you don't cause any errors or down time on the website.