# unable to use my wordpress site after moving

Tags: database, installation

I downloaded my wordpress site and using it on localhost, but I couldn't. I changed my url in mysql db and followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557718/after-migration-of-wordpress-website-i-cant-access-the-admin-white-page) . still I do not have access to my website or wp-admin.

I have https://localhost:8888/nofel/invest/davids/wp-admin/

I get 404 but when I do https://localhost:8888/nofel/invest/davids I get a lot of error in console about css, images and other things.

What am I missing?

Comment: Look here: ["How to: Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/how-to-easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production/868#868), ["Moving_WordPress"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: [Codex - Changing_The_Site_URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Answer (score 0):

First login the admin panel

Then click the below menu navigation

Setting >>> Permalink Settings

Then click the Permalink Settings page save changes button.

Comment: I don't have wp-admin access

Comment: Please check root folder if htaccess available remove the .htaccess file. Enable to show hidden file option and then check the .htaccess file.

Comment: I removed it, it is working but images and css are broken

Comment: @DCReddish97 Now do this admin panel Permalink Settings changes.

Comment: some links are fine, some link just go to localhost/site which break the site. still images are broken

Comment: Check the broken link. it's may be defined in statically in page content or link.

Comment: yes, menu in css is broken too and images too

Answer (score 0):

Take your .htaccess file located in projects root folder. then change the url there .
change your live url and set it as localhost url

it will work